# Enumerable.Concat not working on empty list

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I have below code which retrieves a list from a subfunction and returns it back to a main function. My problem is I cannot concatenate the result from the subfunc to the enumerable declared in mainfunc. Is there something I am missing?

```
private void MainFunc()
{
    IEnumerable<CustomClass> keys = Enumerable.Empty<CustomClass>();
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        keys.Concat(SubFunc(item));
    }
}
private IEnumerable<CustomClass> SubFunc (string y)
{
    IEnumerable<CustomClass> list = GetList(y).ToList();
    return list;
}
```

Comment: You can use Add or AddRange methods instead of using those pure methods(CONCAT).

Answer (score 13):

`.Concat()` does not mutate the subject, but returns a *new* `IEnumerable<T>`.

You're just throwing it away.

Fix your code with:

```
keys = keys.Concat(SubFunc(item))
```